# it running properly but after four post it show the spawn error in log stream (AWS)

Tags: amazon-sqs

In log stream(aws) after four post run succefully  after its shows this error in log stream

```
spawn ENOMEM
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn
     (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
    at Launcher.launch (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteercore/lib/Launcher.js:126:40)
    at <anonymous> code: 'ENOMEM', errno: 'ENOMEM', syscall: 'spawn' }
```